# rsync --dry-run then rsync --files-from

Tags: linux, rsync

I backup big folders and at first I run `rsync ... --dry-run` to verify the list of files.

Then I used to execute the same command, but this time without `--dry-run` to transfer the files.

Because it was scanning files twice, I thought of an improvement: I redirected the output of `rsync ... --dry-run` to a file, removed all noise and leaving only file names, and I passed that list to `rsync ... --files-from=FILE`.

It worked fine until there was a file that should be deleted:

```
*deleting   Downloads/2022-09.pdf
```

Well, rsync complained about the missing file and did not delete at destination...

```
rsync: link_stat "/mnt/c/Downloads/2022-09.pdf" failed: No such file or directory (2)
```

Is there any way to redo a dry run without scanning all files twice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output of `rsync` is not intended to be its input to another instance. You might be able to achieve something with the `--out-format` option, but it will still break when it comes to flagging deleted files.

The time spent scanning should be insignificant to the time that would be spent copying all the files, so although it might seem to take a long time it's still a better optimisation than simply copying.

Conclusion? Don't try to cheat the system; just let `rsync` to do what it does well in the way that it wants to do it. For efficiency, ensure that you're using at least `rsync -t` (`--times`), and that you have not specified `-c` (`--checksum`) unless you *really* understand the very rare cases where it's necessary. I've seen too many people use `-c` because they think it's necessary when it's not, and it slows down `rsync` by a factor of hundreds if not thousands. (If in doubt, add your command to the question and I'll review it.)

Comment: Thank you, that's what I was afraid. I was not using -c. I decided to not update this question, because there is another q regarding performance. I'd be grateful if you checked my commands, as your offered :) https://superuser.com/questions/1746260/rsync-very-slow-file-comparison